# When I minimize my HTML/CSS page, it squishes all the pictures and texts and ruins the formatting

Tags: html, css

When I minimize my HTML/CSS page it squishes all the pictures and texts and ruins the formatting.

[Image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeWmC.png)

Link of my image how its need to be while minimize : https://ibb.co/hOQEWp

My codes:

```css
body {
}
#Title
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    font-size:32.5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color:black;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 0.5px black;
}
#BeitarVsSachninText
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px; 
}
#BeitarVsSachninPicture
{
        position: absolute;
     left: 920px;
     bottom:51px;
}
#BeitarVsSachninPicture2
{
        position: absolute;
     left: 525px;
     bottom:51px;
}
#TextForPictures
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:red;
    font-size:15px; 
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 0.5px black;
}
#TextForPictures2
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:yellow;
    font-size:15px; 
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 0.5px black;
}
#VeredPicture
{
        position: absolute;
     left: 745px;
     margin:auto;
     bottom:-250px;
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BetiarVsSachin.aspx.cs" Inherits="BetiarVsSachin" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <link rel = "Stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "BeitarVsSachnin.css" />
   <link href="Animate.css" rel = "Stylesheet" type = "text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id = "Title">ואהבת לרעך כמוך</div>
<div id = "BeitarVsSachninText">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
&nbsp; קהל החוץ חזר הערב (שני) למפגשים בין בית&quot;ר י-ם לבני סכנין, ויחד איתו קיבלנו את 
    אחד המשחקים<br />
&nbsp; הכי טובים שראינו העונה. טדי עמוס באוהדים ונטול אלימות, חמישה שערים ודרמה 
    אדירה הביאו<br />
&nbsp; לניצחון ראשון העונה של בית&quot;ר, 2:3 על סכנין, שאולי יוציא את החבורה של גיא 
    לוזון לדרך חדשה. האורחת<br />
&nbsp; הייתה טובה יותר ברוב שלבי המשחק, אבל בני בן זקן לא יכול להיות שבע רצון עם 
    שלוש נקודות בלבד<br />
&nbsp; בקופה.<br />
    <br />
&nbsp; כן ירבו משחקים כאלה בליגת העל. אם פעם התעסקנו לפני מפגשים כאלה בהיערכות 
    משטרתית, הערב<br />
&nbsp; שחקני בית&quot;ר עלו לחימום עם הכיתוב &quot;ואהבת לרעך כמוך&quot; על חולצותיהם. לפני שריקת 
    הפתיחה האקסים<br />
&nbsp; קלאודמיר ובן זקן קיבלו פרחים, אבל הקבוצה המארחת ידעה שעם כל הרצון הטוב, כל 
    דבר מלבד ניצחון לא<br />
&nbsp; יתקבל בברכה. משה חוגג התמקם בלב היציע המזרחי, אבל הפתיחה הייתה כולה של סכנין.<br />
&nbsp; האורחת, מחוזקת ב-1000 אוהדים,&nbsp; שכבה על השער של דודו גורש בדקות הפתיחה, 
    אבל שתי החמצות<br />
&nbsp; ענק של שלומי אזולאי ועוד מיני החמצה של סארי פלאח השאירו את התוצאה על כנה. 
    הלישאה אומרת שמי<br />
&nbsp; שלא כובש, סופג, וזה בדיוק מה שקרה. אינברום מצא את ורד במרכז הרחבה והקשר 
    המצוין, איש המשחק,<br />
&nbsp; הכניע את קנדיל שיכול היה להגיב טוב יותר (דקה 13).<br />
    <br />
&nbsp; למרות אין ספור מצבים מצונים של סכנין גורש הצליח לנעול את השער. במחצית השנייה 
    קיבלנו כבר<br />
&nbsp; קונצרט של כדורגל. שיתוף פעולה נהדר בין אזולאי לגאדיר הסתיים בשער השוויון של 
    האחרון (דקה 51), שערך<br />
&nbsp; בכורה בהרכב. האורח כבר חשבה שהמשחק הולך לכיוון שלה, אבל בית&quot;ר שוב הכתה בניגוד 
    למהלך<br />
&nbsp; המשחק. אינברום, שבישל את הראשון, בעט כדור חזק לפינת השער של קנדיל שלא יכול 
    היה להושיע (דקה 59).<br />
&nbsp; השער השני שבר את הרוח של סכנין שדי איבדה אמונה ביכולת שלה לחזור לעניינים. מי 
    שניצל זאת כדי<br />
&nbsp; לקרב את המארחת לניצחון היה אפונסו טיירה שכבש שער ראשון בישראל אחרי שיצא לטיול 
    בעורף של סכנין (דקה 80).<br />
&nbsp; סכנין עוד ניסתה להחזיר את המשחק לחיים לאחר שאקפביו כבש שער בכורה במדי קבוצתו 
    (דקה 88), אבל<br />
&nbsp; זו הייתה שירת הברבור של סכנין שלמרות שהייתה טובה יותר, היא רשמה הפסד ראשון 
    העונה. בית&quot;ר עדיין<br />
&nbsp; לא יכולה לחגוג, אבל יכול להיות שהניצחון הזה מבשר על יציאה לדרך חדשה, על פי 
    החזון של מש חוגג.</div>
    <div id = "BeitarVsSachninPicture" class = "animated zoomIn">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" 
            ImageUrl="~/SoccerPage/BeitarVsSachnin.jpg" Height="250px" Width="330px" />
    </div>
    <div id = "BeitarVsSachninPicture2" class = "animated zoomIn">
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="250px" 
            ImageUrl="~/SoccerPage/BeitarVsSachnin2.jpg" Width="330px" />
    </div>
    <div id = "TextForPictures" class = "animated bounceInLeft">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        קרב ענקים בין אזולאי לקריאף&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        גאדיר חוגג עם שער אדיר</div>
        <div id = "VeredPicture" class = "animated zoomIn">
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="250px" 
                ImageUrl="~/SoccerPage/BeitarVsSachnin3.jpg" Width="330px" />
    </div>
    <div id = "TextForPictures2" class = "animated bounceInLeft">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        ורד ממשיך להפציץ - שחקן ענק!</div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that while I minimize it all the pictures are squished.

Comment: Define minimise? Generally, you want to be exploring [responsive CSS design patterns](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/).

Comment: Yes i dont know how to do it bro :(

Comment: Read the linked article. Use Google searches or Bing searches. Put some effort into researching before asking for help here.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning for layout - it should only be used if you want to place something on top of something else out of the natural flow of the page.  Do some tutorials and learn css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS

Comment: What do you mean bro? Where i need to remove the absoulute position?

Comment: What are the odds of the chatty title here being a [word-for-word copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371560/when-i-minimize-my-html-css-page-it-squishes-all-the-pictures-and-texts-and-ruin) of an unrelated question from five years ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I minimize my HTML/CSS page it squishes all the pictures and texts and ruins the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371560/when-i-minimize-my-html-css-page-it-squishes-all-the-pictures-and-texts-and-ruin)

Comment: @halfer hahahahaha ohhh Stackoverflow, what a crazzzzzy place! Thanks `:-)`

Comment: @JBDouble05 and the same answer holds true -- get Bootstrap 2!! `:-)`